# Marginalization BN

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, bayesian-network

Is my marginalization over C of P(A)P(B)P(C|A,B)P(D|C)P(E|C) below correct? Because wouldn't this imply that there are no dependencies once you marginalize over C?

[image]